# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (**) has no segue with identifier '**''

Tags: ios, segue

I really hope this has not been asked before.  I have spent quite a bit of time on this site looking for a solution but haven't been able to come up with one.  I am trying to call performSegueWithIdentifier from a function called callPerformSegue.  callPerformSegue gets called when a UIImageView in the footer of a section in a UITableView is clicked. The callPerformSegue function is below:

```
- (void)callPerformSegue {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bannerPressed" sender:self];
}
```

I have the bannerPressed segue identified correctly in the Storyboard, since if I move the performSegueWithIdentifier call into didSelectRowAtIndexPath, the segue gets executed correctly.  However, when called from callPerformSegue, I get the following:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (****) has no segue with identifier 'bannerPressed''

Any ideas?

### UPDATE:

I call the function callPerformSegue from my BannerView class, which is a subclass of UIImageView.  This class handles the touch event when someone clicks on a banner, and determines which image was displayed when the touch was received.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //Get the time of the click
    NSDate *animationStart;
    NSDate *clickTime;
    clickTime = [NSDate date];

    NSMutableArray *bannerArrayFromDictionary = [self.bannerDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.currentSection]];

    //Calculate the time elapsed since animationStart and clickTime
    animationStart = [bannerArrayFromDictionary objectAtIndex:0];

    int secondsElapsed = [clickTime timeIntervalSinceDate:animationStart];

    //Determine the number of elements for the section
    int numberOfImagesForSection = [bannerArrayFromDictionary count] - 1;

    //Determine the index into the animationArrary
    int imageClickedIndex = (secondsElapsed / 5) % numberOfImagesForSection;

    //Add 1 to the index to compensate for the timestamp
    imageClickedIndex++;

    //Get the image name
    NSString *clickedImage = [bannerArrayFromDictionary objectAtIndex:imageClickedIndex];

    //Set the image name in CategoryViewController so that a segue to the Detail Page can be performed
    CategoryViewController *view = [[CategoryViewController alloc] init];
    view.currentImage = clickedImage;
    [view callPerformSegue];

}
```

Comment: how did you call the method callPerformSegue?

Comment: Thanks for the response @lu yuan, I updated my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BannerView.h

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet id  delegate;
```

BannerView.m

```
[self.delegate callPerformSegue];
```

CategoryViewController.m

```
bannerView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I apologize @lu yuan, but I'm feeling very dense right now.  I've only been learning iOS a couple months now in my spare time so I have a ton to learn.  I have several segues from the CategoryViewController VC and they all work correctly.  The bannerView UIImageView is created programmatically in viewForFooterInSection in CategoryViewController only if a banner is to be displayed in a section.  If that UIImageVIew is clicked, the touchesBegan function is executed which should then call callPerformSegue.

Comment: Thanks again @lu yuan.  I added the outlet in BannerView.h (I had to forward declare the CategoryViewController class though in BannerView.h.  I tried importing CategoryViewController.h in BannerView.h but I guess there was a circular reference problem because I had #import BannerView.h in CategoryViewController.h and it couldn't find BannerView), and added the code in BannerView.m.  However, I am unable to link the CategoryViewController view to the outlet in BannerView.h.  Seems that I can only link to an outlet in CategoryViewController.h.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: @user1292943 Then, try to set the BannerView's delegate to the CategoryViewController.h, and call [self.delegate callPerformSegue]. I will Update the answer for you, wait for a second.

Comment: Thanks once more @lu yuan, I updated my code based on your answer, but the callPerformSegue function in CategoryViewController doesn't get called.  Does that outlet need to get wired somehow?  What did you mean by "try to set the BannerView's delegate to the CategoryViewController.h"?  Is there something I need to add in CategoryViewController.h?  I do have the following in the interface section of CategoryViewController.h:  BannerView *view;

Comment: @user1292943 No need to wire something now. Could you plz show me more related codes? such as how you add the bannerview?

Comment: Well, I did get the callPerformSegue to execute clicking on a different banner.  I think I may have some sort of SQL database issue.    But, what you posted seems to be working.  I'll mark this as answered and make another post if I can't figure out this other issue.  Thanks so much for your help!  I very much appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the Segue wired up to the TableView cell and not to the ViewController.  I make it a habit to always wire up Segues to the VC and not to Buttons or TableView Cells.  To fix, delete the Segue you have now and re-wire it to the VC and not the TableView Cell.  Make sure to name it the same.

Comment: Thanks @ElJay, that's actually one of the first things I've tried (also did it again just now), and still have the issue.  I have quite a few different view controllers and segues in my project and wrestled with that before.